# Preventing a page from getting opened

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When user clicks on a chart, I get some `ID` in the Javascript side of its `onclick` event and pass that as a **query param** to the page that I want to open and I say

```
window.open(go_to);
```

which `goto` will have that query param in it for exampel like `"http://localhost:3000/myapp/people?provider=134"`

so now it hits the `index` action method in the Rails side, in there I also get another variable for logged in user:

```
def index
  cur_user_id = current_user.id
  provider_id = params[:provider]

  # call the REST service and pass those two params
  # and get the appropriate JSON back from the service

  if provider_id == cur_user_id
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

The problem I have is with this logic:

```
  if provider_id == cur_user_id
    render nothing: true
  end
```

So **if logged in user is the same as the provider I don't want to open that page or show anything.** `Render Nothing` is helping with not showing anything but still the `window.open` part of the code from Javascript is opening the page, blank tho
How can I tell it hey don't even open the new page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ruby code mixed with javascript:

```
var provider_id = $('#provider_id').val();
var go_to = '/path/to/somewhere?provider_id=' + provider_id;
if(provider_id == <%= current_user.id %>) {
  alert('You cannot go there!');
} else {
  window.open(go_to);
}
```

Remember that the ruby code will be executed first (on server-side), then your HTML/javascript will be generated, and finally be executed on the client-side. So `<%= current_user.id %>` inside the javascript will just print the value in there, like if it was hard-coded in JS.

---

It seems that you didn't know about the ruby code inside the javascript parts, to give you an example, try this in one of your view using Javascript:

```
# this is on the server-side, it will be generated:
<script type="text/javascript">
  <%= "alert('hello Eric!');".html_safe %>
</script>

# on the client-side, you will receive this generated HTML content:
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('hello Eric!');
</script>
```

**For HAML:**

```
:javascript
  #{"alert('hello Eric')".html_safe}
  var hello = '#{"hello World!"}';
  alert(hello);
```

Comment: wait what? I use use Ruby code inside JavaScript code?  What is the syntax to mark it as Ruby code? Can you please give me some reference to learn more about it or if you just explain it more yourself. Thanks.

Comment: You know that you can use `<%= %>` tags (in ERB) to execute & print ruby code in your HTML page, right? Well it works the same way for Javascript: The JS is executed on the client-side, first it needs to be rendered on the server-side. So you can use `<%= %>` code in the javascript part.

Comment: yep I knew about ERB,HTML part only.. so now I typed  var ohWow = <%= current_user.id %>;  in my JS side and it marks it as syntax error saying XML element expected.  Is it because I am using HAML? I don't think so...

Comment: Yes it is because you use HAML ;) I'll post an example for HAML in a sec: use the regular `#{ruby code in here}` to print ruby code in the Javascript part with HAML.